# Defining functions for multiple data sets

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have bunch of data sets and their names are like;

```
df_a
df_b
df_c
df_d
...
```

All the data sets have the same columns,
My question is, I want to apply some functions all the data sets.

The functions are like:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['day_of_week'] = df.date.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%A"))
```

But I don't want to write these and another functions for all data sets separately. Is there any solution for for writing these functions in short cut for all data frames?

Comment: Put them in a list and iterate through them and use them in your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs = [df_a, df_b, ...]

for dataset in dfs:
    do_thing(dataset)
```

Comment: Please provide a little context and explanation of your answer.